# What if everyone is on the same team?

Tags: civilization-5

Is it possible to set up a game and have all of the bots be on the same team? Would you gain the benefits of the AI civs cheating? Would you get super science from a shared tree? Would a military victory be unobtainable, very easy, or instant? I'm curious what would happen in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't actually start a game with everyone on the same team.  The "Start Game" button is grayed out, and it specifically says:

> You must have at least 2 teams.

Comment: Is it possible to start with everyone as allies if not on the same team?

Comment: Proof that there will never be world peace. :(